# How to get columns values after insert using php mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

In this code, after insert values to DB.I am doing select query for selecting invoiceNo($sql1= "select invoiceNo from invoices order by invoiceID desc limit 1"; ).Instead of selecting from DB how to get InvoiceNo?

For eg: Assume two users are there.Two users inserts InvoiceID at a same time.While doing "select invoiceNo from invoices order by invoiceID desc limit 1";this will get last coming invoiceID .I need to get specific invoiceID (for particular user) .How to get it?

```
$query          = "select * from invoices order by invoiceID desc limit 1";
$result         = $link->query($query);
$row            = $result->fetch_assoc();
$invoiceNo      = $row["invoiceNo"];
$getinvoiceNo   = str_pad($invoiceNo + 1, 4, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT); //inserting like 0000
$sql            = "INSERT INTO invoices (invoiceNo)
                   VALUES ('$getinvoiceNo')";
if ($link->query($sql) === TRUE) {
   //echo "1";
   $sql1    = "select invoiceNo from invoices order by invoiceID desc limit 1";
   $last_id = mysqli_insert_id($link, $sql1);
   $result1 = mysqli_query($link, $sql1);
   $row1    = mysqli_fetch_array($result1);
   echo json_encode($row1);
} else {
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}
mysql_close($link);
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Ever thinked or heard about Auto-Increment column on DataBases?

Comment: Set one of the columns to be unique, then use `INSERT IGNORE`, `INSERT REPLACE`, or `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

Comment: in db InvoceID is unique

Comment: You're mixing mysql-api's. `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*` are two completely different API's and are not interchangeable. You should also stick to either the OOP version _or_ the procedural version of mysqli. Mixing them just makes it easier to make mistakes and makes it harder to read.

Comment: If all you want is an incrementing number then why don't you use an `AUTOINCREMENT` field?  It does exactly that.

Comment: invoice ID is auto incre and primary key.InvoiceNo should be 1001,1002 like that and invoiceNo is unique

Comment: @blackwhite: So your table has *two* incrementing identifiers?  Seems like you're duplicating concerns in the design.  You have an identifier for your invoices, and then you also have an identifier for your invoices.  See the problem there?

Comment: IMO, the public invoice id should not be the PK.

Comment: for example when two user click save button at same time.insertion should not be happen i need to stop second user to insert and second user needs to click again save button for insert values?whats the solution?

Comment: it'd be nice if you added every clarification you're giving to the question's body, so that everyone can see it without needing to go through the comments.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your question correctly, you are concerned about possible data corruption from the concurrent update of the record.

I think you should give a look to mysql [SELECT ... FOR UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html) syntax, it should do what you ask: lock the selected row until an update is fired. Then the lock will be released.

For example:

```
SELECT table_field FROM table_name WHERE table_id_field = id_param FOR UPDATE
```

will lock the selected row until

```
UPDATE table_name SET table_field = table_field + 1 WHERE table_id_field = id_param
```

Comment: for example when two user click save button at same time.insertion should not be happen i need to stop second user to insert and second user needs to click again save button for insert values?whats the solution?

Comment: i really think you should go on and try it. The FOR UPDATE (used inside a transaction) WILL lock your table  after the SELECT, and user 2 will not be able to make changes to the database, untill user 1 finished its update.

Comment: Here am doing insertion not updation.so there no id before insertion.so what to do when inserting new rows?

Comment: now i get what you mean, my bad. If that is the case, i really think you should use an auto-increment field as many others have suggested, the design seems just flawed

Comment: already invoice id in autoincre and primary key.i cant make invoice no be autoincrement right?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to prevent collisions in invoice numbers, all you need to do is create your table as

```
CREATE TABLE invoices (
     invoiceID INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     other columns . . .
     PRIMARY KEY (invoiceID)
);
```

Then when you do your INSERT, don't insert the invoiceID and let MySQL do it.

This will ensure that each new invoice has a unique invoiceID.

Comment: no invoiceID is autocrement and primary key.i dont want to change this.If u have anyother idea plz tell me

Comment: if ten user inserting 10 records,exception will come here.And also after insertion i am selecting invoiceNo ( "select invoiceNo from invoices order by invoiceID desc limit 1";)So first user will get the invoiceNo of 10th user right.So i need a solution for this

Comment: If you have an IDENTITY Column, you can **not** do the insert. It will fail. You can get the auto-incremented IDENTITY for your insert with `$link->insert_id` this will be correct for each connection no matter how many users you have.

Comment: i have two columns in db invoiceID and invoiceNo are different

Comment: "already invoiceNo is unique in database.This is fine?" I don't see why not. Is there some reason you also need an invoiceID? What's the difference between the two?

Comment: yes. invoiceID will be 1 2 3 4 5 and invoiceNo should be 1001 1002 1003.

Comment: instead of select * from invoices order by invoiceID desc limit 1 .Is there any other solution for selecting becoz 20k records are there in database

Comment: I'm really confused as to what you're actually trying to do. Normally you would select the invoice you want with `SELECT col1, col2, etc FROM invoices WHERE invoiceNo = 1` or whatever you're looking for and it would return one row.

Comment: am selecting last invoiceno (eg:2) and while inserting invoiceno(2+1=3).already i mention in code [str_pad($invoiceNo + 1, 4, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT)]

Comment: My question is if more than two user inserting values at same time(insert values at same time).what will happen when selecting invoiceNo?

Comment: "while inserting invoiceno(2+1=3)." Sorry, I can't help you. You need to redesign your process. Doing math on unique identifiers is just looking for an overly complicated design and a lot of trouble.